# Django chatterbot response is not showing in chat window

Tags: python, django, chatterbot

i am trying Django chatterbot. when i want to interact with bot, bot's response is not showing in chat window. 
please check the attached image.[image]

There is no error in code when i am running it.

i also tried

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate

python manage.py migrate django_chatterbot
python manage.py train
```

i am unable to figure out the problem.
Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: Please show the javascript or template of your chat window. I guess you are not writing any code to update the chat window after got the botter response. Do you ?

Comment: i have not written any code here. some times it is showing response in chat window and sometimes it is not showing. i am using sample example code provided by chatterbot. all functions written here.

Comment: you can check code here. https://github.com/gunthercox/ChatterBot/tree/1a2ab56eeecfacde650cc31009b8025e8bd21189/examples/django_app

Comment: I tried to run this in incognito window. it is sending responses in chat window. working fine here.